# Disable Velocity view resolver in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, velocity

We use Spring Boot in our application along with AngularJS and HTML. We use Velocity only for email templates but not for view resolver.

```
@Bean(name = "velocityEngine")
public VelocityEngineFactoryBean velocityEngineFactoryBean() {
    VelocityEngineFactoryBean vefb = new VelocityEngineFactoryBean();
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("resource.loader", "class");
    p.put("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
    vefb.setVelocityProperties(p);
    return vefb;
}
```

Even though we don't use Velocity view resolver, we get the following error due to auto-configuration:

> ERROR org.apache.velocity - ResourceManager: unable to find a resource
>   'LoadList' in any resource loader. ERROR org.apache.velocity -
>   ResourceManager: unable to find resource 'index' in any resource
>   loader.

I tried to disable Velocity auto configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,VelocityAutoConfiguration.class })
@SuppressWarnings("PMD")
@EnableAsync
public class Application {
```

Also added the following in the application.properties file:

```
spring.velocity.check-template-location=false
```

But I'm still getting the above error. Is there any way to disable the Velocity view resolver alone?

Comment: The exclude should be sufficient to disable the Velocity auto-configuration (it works for me). Two possibilities: you have another `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation in your application that doesn't have the exclude configured; the auto-configuration is disabled and the error you're seeing is due to something else. Perhaps you could post the auto-configuration report and the full stack trace that goes with the error?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I had @EnableAutoConfiguration at some other file also. Its working fine after excluding on the other file also.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I need to set spring.velocity.enabled=false to disable the Velocity mvc view resolver. But I am using Velocity for email templates, and setting spring.velocity.enabled=false has the consequence that VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "/mailing.txt", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name(), model); does not find the file "mailing.txt" anymore when the project is running as WAR-file. While running in eclipse it still works.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is quite old, but it is quite easy to disable:

just add

```
spring.velocity.enabled = false
```

to the application.properties

Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 1):

In Spring boot, With Annotation, you can exclude the VelocityAutoConfiguration like

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {VelocityAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```